# Identify cells containing a set of strings

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, contains, conditional-formatting

I have about 18,000 rows of different item descriptions. Let's say an item is called like this: `Elbow 45, Steel, Swivel, 4"` but it is not always written in this order. Sometimes the same part is written in a different order like this:

`Elbow, 45, Swivel, 4", Steel`
or
`Steel, 45, Elbow, Swivel, 4"`

If I try to find it with Crtl+f, it does not work because I have to type in exactly what a cell contains in the exact order.

Can I also search for example: Find me all cells which contain "Elbow" and "Swivel" and "Steel" and so on and it will show me all cells?

Comment: Thank you, they are in a single column.

Comment: They are all in a single cell. I all depend how much I know about an Item. I just want to know where all three (more?) are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameters (say `Steel` to E1, `Elbow` to E2 and `Swivel` to E3) and select the column (assumed to be ColumnA), HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(SEARCH($E$1,A1)>0,SEARCH($E$2,A1)>0,SEARCH($E$3,A1)>0)
```

and select a fill colour.

Comment: Thank you that helps, but is there a way I can see all results combined instead scrolling through 18000 rows?

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great. It is not very easy but it works.